# Should I train my model with a set of pictures as one input data or I need to crop to small one using Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I see two methods how to train model:

- training based on one picture with my true predict of decision
- training based on one big picture with set of pics inside and keep training like sets with my true predict of decision

Predict input may be as one picture or sets

If you have suggestions, will be nice to hear your best practice for
how to properly give training input
how to properly give predict input

Now I keep training my model with inputs as sets and big separated images.
I receive answers based on one picture or sets as predict input.